# How to check if a script is still running in my server?

Tags: python, pandas, server, putty, vps

So I started a script that sends me an email if a specific condition occours and its running from vps, but since I've not yet received any emails, I'm wondering if the script is still running. I also forgot the name of the "xxxxxx.py" file thats running.

What can I do??

Comment: Did you run it from SSH? If yes, closing the shell will end the script

Comment: Try this: ps -x | grep ".py"
It should pull up all processes that are from python

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't list my script as running. I beleive that I used nano to make the script, is there a way to check the file names of the nano scripts that are on the server?

Comment: I'm interfacing with the server in putty, but i'm not using SSH, just root user and a password

Comment: I found the name of the script, address_tracker_script.py. It appears its not running. how can I check the run command "python3 address_tracker_script.py" to see if it has run the script?

Comment: nvm, the script is definitely running now

Comment: how do I leave it running so i can close the terminal window?

Comment: maybe that can be helpful in future. Usually i check if server running or not with  run that script on terminal `lsof -i tcp:3000` (3000 is depends on your server, 5000 etc). you can see all list of running `3000` or whatever you r checking.

Answer (score 0):

If your VPS is linux-based with a ssh server listening, you should be able to connect to it, opening a terminal. After that You can try using the `ps ax` or `top` or `htop` command to display all processes running.

You can then use a pipe to filter out the word "py" :
`ps ax | grep "py"`

Answer (score 0):

Using the ps command with -A and -f flags and pipe the output to grep and search for `py`
Check this :

```
ps -A -f | grep "py"
```